# I Want To Load My Products As A Grid Using Php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, backend

I am building a site, I want to load all products as a grid of `col-md-6` on desktop devices but I used this code below but it's loading differently. What Should I do?

```
<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <h5><?php the_title(); ?><br>
                <form><button class="button-default" type="submit"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> View Product Details</button></form>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php $row ?>
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p>
     <?php _e( 'No Products'); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's loading differently"?

Comment: @Hentry  screenshot it is possibe? cause you geeting  problem through code or design wise?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want it each product to load two per row

Comment: @Samyappa this is a screenshot of how I want it to load and not to load

[link](https://ibb.co/g9tWJ9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define container class outside the loop. Try this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            $wc_query->the_post(); ?>


    <div class="col-md-6">

            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?><br>
            <form><button class="button-default" type="submit"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> View Product Details</button></form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php $row ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p>
 <?php _e( 'No Products'); ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have solved my problem. Thanks very much!